# How to set individual bar color in excel chart using epplus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I want to set individual bar color of bar chart in excel using epplus.
Please see the below code.

```
ExcelWorksheet wsGraph = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Graph");
wsGraph.Cells["D2"].LoadFromDataTable(dtGraph, true);
ExcelBarChart chat =(ExcelBarChart) wsGraph.Drawings.AddChart("Status", eChartType.BarClustered);
chat.Title.Text= "Tickets Status";
chat.SetPosition(1, 0, 3, 0);
chat.SetSize(500, 300);
chat.Series.Add(wsGraph.Cells["E3:E8"], wsGraph.Cells["D3:D8"]);
```

I want to this type chart.Also set series gap and bar height and width.

[image: I need this type of graph]
[image: Above code showing this graph]

Comment: Here I show how to set colors of individual elements of the different bars of the chart:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356874/epplus-columnstacked-chart-data-point-colors/34403425#34403425